# C# calorie counter

Tags: c#, exception, string-parsing

I am new to programming and taking my first course, programming fundamentals and on our current homework assignment I have a problem I cannot get.

The problem is- "A bag of cookies holds 40 cookies. The calorie information on the bag claims that there are 10 servings in the bag and that a serving equals 300 calories. Create an application that lets the user enter the number of cookies he or she actually ate and then reports the number of calories consumed."

My form:
[image: My form]

The error i get when I run without debugging:
[image: The error i get when I run without debugging]

//below is my code

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Calorie_Counter
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int cookies = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);

            int calories = (cookies * 75);

            textBox2.Text = calories.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please post all error messages and code as text. It's very inconvenient for us to have to click through to see what the error was. Thanks! The problem is that you typed something into the text box that can't be parsed as an integer: "12" can be parsed as an integer. "Six" can't be. "12.1" can't be. "Several" can't be. An empty string can't be either. c# has a [TryParse method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=netframework-4.8) that helps you deal with goofy input

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on how to debug your code. Debugging is a critical skill to learn as a beginning programmer.

Comment: For a beginner I'd suggest starting with console applications.  You can deal with UI stuff latter.

Comment: You might want to use TryParse instead of Parse for this

Comment: Please edit your question and add the full exception message. You can see this exception message if you click on the `Details` button of the error dialog.

Comment: Those must be small cookies.

Answer (score 5):

You encounter this problem when using the `int.Parse()` method. This method simply converts whatever you passed to it as a `string` to `int`. So, something like `"33"` will be converted, but what if you entered something that is clearly not an `integer` such as `"x"` or even an empty string?

So, this will be converted to a value of `33` in `int` type no problem.

```
int parseResultGood = int.Parse("33");
```

But this will fail and throw an exception, because, obviously `"x"` cannot be converted into an integer.

```
int parseResultBad = int.Parse("x");
```

Luckily though, `C#` provides you another method to handle this better, namely, `int.TryPrase()` method. As the name suggests it *tries* to parse the value, and converts it into an `int` only if it is possible and send it back to you in the `out` parameter while it will `return true`. If the conversion failed, say, because you passed a non-integer value as a `string`, it will `return false`, and the value of the `out` parameter will be `zero`. So based on the return value of `true/false` you can know if the conversion was successful or not, and it won't thrown an exception.

```
int tryParseResult = 0;
if (int.TryParse("X", out tryParseResult))
{
    // Use the converted value
}
else
{
    // Display an error message or something similar
}
```

However, I suggest you learn to debug your program. If you did, you'd have been able to figure out the problem for yourself. The article that was linked to in comments is a great one, please follow it. Good luck!

Comment: +1 crystal-clear answer. If I may, i'd separate that and put it in another class in another private function in order to separate the logic of the application with the click event. The click would then call that function and would make the application tidier.